# number of totally different path between two nodes in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected

I have an undirected, unweighted graph representing a network.
I have a starting node and an end one.
My 'network' is reliable if there is no node such that without that node s and t are not reachable i.e. no node is necessary and all nodes have at least one redundant path.

how can I formally verify this?
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "formally verify"? What do you mean that "all nodes have at least one redundant path"? 

Comment: As stated by Igor, you want biconnectivity.  A naive way to check this is to check, for each vertex $v$, that $G-v$ is connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that the network remains connected upon removing any one node, the magic words are "2-vertex-connected graph", or "biconnected graph". An algorithm for determining biconnectivity is described [here](http://garryowen.csisdmz.ul.ie/~cs4115/resources/lect24.pdf), though I am sure there are plenty of other places.

Comment: Btw, the OP has stated (without proof) a special case of Menger's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate number of paths from one node to another ,let say from s to t.then you can follow the following approach.

To reach a node t from s , you need to calculate that how many ways are there to reach t from its adjacent vertices .
means
 PathsTo(s,t)=sum(PathsTo(s,u)) , where u are adjacents vertices of t.

as we can see there is a subproblem optimality and overlapping subproblems, so we can use a DP approach to do this in Linear time.

We can do this by modifying our DFS algorithm.

Psuedocode:

declare an array A of size |V| , memset it to NULL
array represent , number of ways to reach a node v from s.

Paths(s,t):

if(s==t):

```
 return 1;
```

else:

```
 if(A[t]==NULL):
      A[t]=sum(Paths(s,u)) for all adjacent u of t
 else
      return A[t]
```

Time complexity is O(V+E) same as DFS.